How to allow selecting taxonomy in Wordpress
I create a custom post type called video in Wordpress. I associated a new video_category taxonomy to the video. I do see the video_category on the navigation menu where I can create new values.
However, I don't see the list of taxonomy listed when adding or editing existing video. How can add the taxonomy to the video type so the user is able to associate one or more view_category to the video using the edit/new page?
This is the code I am using
function video_register() {   
    $labels = array( 
        'name'                  => _x('Video', 'post type general name'), 
        'singular_name'         => _x('Video Item', 'post type singular name'), 
        'add_new'               => _x('Add New', 'work item'), 
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add New video Item'), 
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit video Item'), 
        'new_item'              => __('New Video Item'), 
        'view_item'             => __('View Video Item'), 
        'search_items'          => __('Search Video'), 
        'not_found'             => __('Nothing found'), 
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Nothing found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon'     => '' 
    );   

    $args = array( 
        'labels'                => $labels, 
        'public'                => true, 
        'publicly_queryable'    => true, 
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true, 
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'videos-list', 'with_front'=> false), 
        'capability_type'       => 'post', 
        'hierarchical'          => false, 
        'menu_position'         => null, 
        'supports'              => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt'),
        'taxonomies'            => array('video_category')
    );   

    register_post_type('video', $args); 
}
add_action('init', 'video_register');

function create_video_category_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x('Video Categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name'     => _x('Video Category', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items'      => __('Search Video Categories'),
        'all_items'         => __('All Video Categories'),
        'parent_item'       => __('Parent Video Category'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Video Category:'),
        'edit_item'         => __('Edit Video Category'),
        'update_item'       => __('Update Video Category'),
        'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Video Category'),
        'new_item_name'     => __('New Video Category Name'),
        'menu_name'         => __('Video Categories'),
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'video-category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('video_category', 'video', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_video_category_taxonomy');


Please update your question with the code that registers your custom taxonomy.

@Caleb its already there. Please look at the create_video_category_taxonomy function it already does it register_taxonomy('video_category', 'video', $args);

Oh my mistake: missed that the code block could be scrolled.

Suggest registering the custom taxonomy before registering the custom post type. If that doesn't work, then try setting show_in_rest on the taxonomy config to true.

I tried both approaches. Neither one worked.

Check screen options?
